# How can I apply multiple strings manipulations in a comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, replace

What i want to write a **list comprehension** where i can apply ***all rules***.

```
def splitting(g):

    return[i.replace('<<', '') for i in g]
    and return[i.replace('>>', '') for i in g] 
    and return[i.replace('?', '') for i in g]
    and return[i.replace(':', '') for i in g]
    and return[i.replace('.', '') for i in g]
    and return[i.replace(',', '') for i in g]
    and return ([i for element in g for i in element.split()])
```

Input Example:

```
['use of a book>> hahaha true<< however:']
```

Output Example:

```
['use of a book hahaha true however']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: the first return actually works...my question is how i write the code so all return runs simultaneously because when i put "and return" it appear some error which makes sense( appearing the error xD).

Comment: Is the input a string?

Comment: its a list of a string... its like ["use of a book>> hahaha true<< however:"]

Comment: Well call it like: ‘nono = splitting(nono[0])’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's character based then simple comprehension could do, something like this:

```
>>> message = '#1 Alice!'
>>> elimination = ['#', '!']
>>> ''.join(letter for letter in message if letter not in elimination)
'1 Alice'
```

EDIT: and if it's list of strings then of course one can just do:

```
>>> my_secret =  ["use of a book>> hahaha true<< however:"]
>>> elimination = ['<', '>', ':']
>>> [''.join(char for char in item if char not in elimination) for item in my_secret]
['use of a book hahaha true however']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an overkill to trying the use list comprehension to replace chars in string (and unnecessary), this one will work:

```
def splitting(g):
    return g.replace('<<', '').replace('>>', '').replace('?', '').replace(':', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '')
wAlice = splitting("Input Example: use of a book>>")
print(wAlice)
```

output:

```
Input Example use of a book
```

If your input is a list of strings' you can use list comprehension ass like in here:

```
def splitting(g):
    return [i.replace('<<', '').replace('>>', '').replace('?', '').replace(':', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '') for i in g]
wAlice = splitting(["Input Example: use of a book>>", "other.string"])
print(wAlice)
```

output:

```
['Input Example use of a book', 'otherstring']
```

Comment: Nope...it appear 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: that's because it wasn't clear that your input is a list, I thought it is a string. fixed the answer according to it. have a try.

Comment: Chaining the `replaces` is also overkill, use regex? Or at least put the `replaces` in a loop.

Comment: It seems to my that chaining .replace is overkill. Why make so many copies? `str.replace - return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new`

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to perform a number of replaces and one return.

```py
def splitting(g):

    g = g.replace('<<', '')
    g = g.replace('>>’, '')
    # more stuff elided
    return g

nono = ['use of a book>> hahaha true<< however:']
nono = splitting(nono[0])
```

Comment: This only works for a string as per your single example.